# Find structure in solidity file

Tags: javascript, regex, nsregularexpression, solidity

I have the next structure in text file: `mapping(address => uint) public lockedAddresses;` and I want find it. I try use the next regular expression: `mapping\s*\([\w\s=>\d]\)\s+(public\s+)?lockedAddresses`. I don`t understand how can I find it.

```js
var string = 'event Release();\n address public holder;\n mapping(address => uint) public lockedAddresses;\n  modifier isReleased () {\n require(released || msg.sender == holder || msg.sender == owner);\n  require(lockedAddresses[msg.sender] <= now);\n  _;\n }';

var position = string.search(/mapping\s*\([()\w\s=>\d]\)\s+(public\s+)?lockedAddresses/);

console.log(position);
```

How can I find structure in text: `mapping(address => uint) public lockedAddresses;`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the character class `[()\w\s=>\d]+` one or more times  to match `address => uint` after the opening parenthesis `(`.

```
mapping\s*\([()\w\s=>\d]+\)\s+(public\s+)?lockedAddresses
                        ^
```

```js
var string = 'event Release();\n address public holder;\n mapping(address => uint) public lockedAddresses;\n  modifier isReleased () {\n require(released || msg.sender == holder || msg.sender == owner);\n  require(lockedAddresses[msg.sender] <= now);\n  _;\n }';
var position = string.search(/mapping\s*\([()\w\s=>\d]+\)\s+(public\s+)?lockedAddresses/);
console.log(position);
```

To fully match `mapping(address => uint) public lockedAddresses;` you should append a semicolon after the regex (and you could make `(public\s+)` a non capturing group):

[`mapping\s*\([()\w\s=>\d]+\)\s+(?:public\s+)?lockedAddresses;`](https://regex101.com/r/YagsPJ/1)